# How to retrive text that was copied (with the CTRL + C command)

Tags: c++, winapi, text, copy-paste, selected

I have a Windows application written in C++.  I want to add a paste option, so that on request the application can retrieve whatever text the user previously copied (i.e., with the control-C command).

Is there a way to do this?

Comment: @IInspectable: I think the OP just wants to implement a paste option.  I've edited the question accordingly.

Comment: thank you Harry Jonhston you exactly explain my intentions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to use the functions `OpenClipboard()`, `GetClipboardData()` and `CloseClipboard()`.

From MSDN:

[Pasting Information from the Clipboard](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms649016(v=vs.85).aspx#_win32_Pasting_Information_from_the_Clipboard)

> 1. Open the clipboard by calling the OpenClipboard function.
> 2. Determine which of the available clipboard formats to retrieve.
> 3. Retrieve the handle to the data in the selected format by calling the GetClipboardData function.
> 4. Insert a copy of the data into the document.
>
>    The handle returned by GetClipboardData is still owned by the clipboard, so an application must not free it or leave it locked.
> 5. Close the clipboard by calling the CloseClipboard function.